# Can we insert two methods in void initState()?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, stateful

This is dumb question but just for the benefit of the doubt, can we insert two methods in a initState? 
E.g:

```
_getCheckpoint1() async {
    var permissions =
        await Permission.getPermissionsStatus([PermissionName.Location]);
    if (permissions[0].permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.notAgain) {
      var askpermissions =
          await Permission.requestPermissions([PermissionName.Location]);
    } else {
      routeCoordinates = await googleMapPolyline.getCoordinatesWithLocation(
          origin: LatLng(3.082519, 101.592201),
          destination: LatLng(3.083355, 101.589653),
          // LatLng(3.082097, 101.585165),
          mode: RouteMode.driving);
    }
  }

  _getCheckPoint2() async {
    var permissions =
        await Permission.getPermissionsStatus([PermissionName.Location]);
    if (permissions[0].permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.notAgain) {
      var askpermissions =
          await Permission.requestPermissions([PermissionName.Location]);
    } else {
      routeCoordinates = await googleMapPolyline.getCoordinatesWithLocation(
          origin: LatLng(3.08171, 101.587507),
          destination: LatLng(3.082519, 101.592201),
          mode: RouteMode.driving);
    }
  }
```

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getCheckpoint1();
    _getCheckPoint2();
  }
```

The reason I'm asking is because I want to generate two different polylines and merge them and form a loop of one big route of polyline through Google Maps plugin.
**I need help**

This is what I intend to do by adding the methods together in an initstate.

[image]
**I need to construct a set of polylines just as illustrated in the picture**

Comment: You are just calling two methods from `initState`. That's what you do with methods... you call them from places. I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: @Abion47 I've edited the post and added more info

Comment: What does constructing a polyline in the google maps widget have to do with "inserting methods in initState"?

Answer (score -1):

you can define an async function in initState but it should be void, not a future

like that :

```dart
void myFutureFunc() async {
  await //My Future 
}
```

you can define many functions as you like.

Comment: `await Future(
       routeCoordinates2 = await googleMapPolyline.getCoordinatesWithLocation(
          origin: LatLng(3.083494, 101.587904),
          destination: LatLng(3.082519, 101.592201),
          mode: RouteMode.driving);
    );`  i tried this and it says argument List<LatLng> can't be assigned to Future

Comment: Future<List<LatLng>> yourFunc() async { await ...  }